# Adding a row in a unittest data base for a FLASK sqlalchemy application

Tags: unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to write some unittests for my flask application and for some reason my database is always empty.

```
import os
import unittest
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from flaskr import create_app
from models import setup_db, Question, Category, db


class TriviaTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """This class represents the trivia test case"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Define test variables and initialize app."""
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client
        self.database_name = "trivia_test"
        self.database_path = "postgres://{}/{}".format('localhost:5432', self.database_name)
        setup_db(self.app, self.database_path)

        self.question = {
            'question': 'is Yaser amazing?',
            'answer': 'of course, are you crazy?',
            'difficulty': 1 ,
            'category': 'all'
        }
        # binds the app to the current context
        with self.app.app_context():
            self.db = SQLAlchemy()
            self.db.init_app(self.app)
            # create all tables
            self.db.create_all()



    def tearDown(self):
        """Executed after reach test"""
        pass
    def test_get_questions(self):
        res = self.client().get('/questions')
        data = json.loads(res.data)
        print(data)

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(data['success'],True)
        self.assertTrue(data['totalQuestions'])
        self.assertTrue(data['all_categories'])
```

I thought that `self.question{}` would add a row in my database but it doesn't. I am not sure if the syntax is right or if it should be something else. I am following a class example and I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding data to your test class object but not adding to your database. To demonstrate:

```
# The following adds a dictionary to `self.question`
self.question = {
    'question': 'is Yaser amazing?',
    'answer': 'of course, are you crazy?',
    'difficulty': 1 ,
    'category': 'all'
    }

# The following assertion should be true
assert isinstance(self.question, dict)
```

To add to your database you would need to do the following:

```
def add_q(self, commit=True):
    """
    Unpack the stored dictionary into your db model,
    then add to your db.
    
    If you'd like to query this object from the db,
    you'll need to commit the session.
    --> Toggle this feature with the param `commit`
    """
    self.db.session.add(Question(**self.question))
    
    # You can also commit outside of the function execution
    # Helpful for batch processing  
    if commit:
        self.db.session.commit()
```

After doing the above, you should be able to query your database for the newly added question. If you're running this test often, you'll likely want to remove the newly added q. Here's a helpful function for that:

```
def remove_q(self, commit=True):
    """
    Query your db for the previously added q. Then
    remove from db.
    
    To commit this change, set commit=True (default)
    """

    my_q = self.db.session.query(Question).filter_by(**self.question).first()
    
    # now delete
    self.db.session.delete(my_q)

    # You can also commit outside of the function execution
    # Helpful for batch processing  
    if commit:
        self.db.session.commit()
```

Comment: its not working for me still for some reason. I did a regular query and its not adding correctly. the weird thing is that in the instructors example they use self.new_boo{} to add a book and it works.

Comment: This might be specific to `unittest.TestCase` then... @MightyPaladin